# window.windowController is nil inside windowWillClose() but it isn't inside viewDidAppear()

Tags: swift, macos, nswindowcontroller

I've tried, without success, respond to events such as `windowWillClose()` and `windowShouldClose()` inside NSWindowController (yes conforming to NSWindowDelegate).

Later, to my surprise, I was able to receive those events if I make my contentViewController (NSViewController) conform to NSWindowDelegate.

Unfortunately, later on, found out that `view.window?.windowController` is `nil` inside `windowWillClose()` or `windowShouldClose()`, code:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    self.view.window?.delegate = self
    self.view.window?.windowController // not nil!
}

func windowWillClose(_ notification: Notification) {
    self.view.window?.windowController // nil!!
}

func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool {
    self.view.window?.windowController // nil!!
    return true
}
```

After realizing that `view.window?.windowController` is not nil inside `viewDidAppear()` the next thing I thought was that Swift garbage collected the controller, so I changed `viewDidAppear()` in a way that creates another reference of `windowController` thus preventing garbage collection on said object, code:

```
var windowController: NSWindowController?

override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    self.view.window?.delegate = self
    windowController = view.window?.windowController
}

func windowWillClose(_ notification: Notification) {
    self.view.window?.windowController // NOT nil
}

func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool {
    self.view.window?.windowController // NOT nil
    return true
}
```

My hypothesis turned out to be correct (I think).

1. Is this the same issue that is preventing me from receiving those events inside NSWindowController?
2. Is there another way I can achieve the same thing without creating more object references?

Comment: `self.view.window.windowController` is `nil`. self.view.window is not.

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce the issue in a small test project?

Comment: @Willeke Ok I'll try to reproduce the issue in a small project.

Comment: Observed exactly the same: calling         print("windowController", self.view.window!, self.view.window!.windowController) in an NSViewController which is the VC of an NSWindowController (defined in IB) returns windowController <NSWindow: 0x600003e0c500> nil.  I tested in the NSWindowController (parent of the VC): func windowDidBecomeMain(_ notification: Notification) {
        print(self.window!)}. The window is correct (0x600003e0c500).   Xcode 11.3 Beta

Comment: And if I print(self.window!.windowController)  in NSWindowController, I get the NSWindowController itself. Is  reference to windowController lost in VC? Xcode 11.3 Beta

Answer (score 0):

In order to post code, I use the Answer option even though it is more of a comment.

I added in `NSViewController`:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    parentWindowController = self.view.window!.windowController
    self.view.window!.delegate = self.view.window!.windowController as! S1W2WC. // The NSWC class, which conforms to NSWindowDelegate
    print(#function, "windowController", self.view.window!, self.view.window!.windowController)
}
```

I get print log:

```
viewDidAppear() windowController <NSWindow: 0x600003e09d00> Optional(<Windows_Demo.S1W2WC: 0x6000021418b0>)
```

and notification is passed.

But if I change to

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
  super.viewDidAppear()
  //  parentWindowController = self.view.window!.windowController
  self.view.window!.delegate = self.view.window!.windowController as! S1W2WC
  print(#function, "windowController", self.view.window!, self.view.window!.windowController)
}
```

By commenting out `parentWindowController`, notification don't go anymore to the `WindowController`…

Edited: I declared in ViewController:

```
var parentWindowController: NSWindowController? // Helps keep a reference to the controller
```

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solutions are, in my opinion, hacks that can cause serious problems with memory management by creating circular references. You definitely can make instances of `NSWindowController` work as the window’s delegate. The proper way is to wire it up correctly in either code or in Interface Builder in Xcode. An example of how to do it properly is offered [here.](https://medium.com/@venj/hide-window-instead-of-close-it-when-clicks-the-close-button-25768e41ee2d)
If the delegate methods are not called is because the wiring up is not done correctly.

Another thing that **must** be done in Swift is when you add the name of the `NSWindowController` subclass in Interface Builder in Xcode is to check the checkbox of `Inherits from Module`. If you fail to do this, none of your subclass methods will be called.